# Does Apple allows html pages rendering at runtime?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, cordova

We have developed web application using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Backbone.js and we need to develop an hybrid version for IOS like gmail app . Our html pages are rendered from server side and then shown on UIWebView.
Does Apple allows such kind of application for App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be allowed as long as you can handle gracefully an offline mode.

Comment: Can you please give a reference?

Comment: I won't be able to give you a reference as it is mostly experience.